# Can I switch to HTML while composing a message?

Tags: thunderbird

I always write plain text mails, so I've set my Thunderbird to compose a plain text message by default and only compose an HTML message, when I hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking *Compose* (or *Reply* or ...).

Sometimes, I see that I would better write an HTML message instead (for example to be able to include an image directly into the message), *after having typed* the recipients, the subject and some greetings and text.

Is there a way to "convert" the message I am currently writing to be a HTML message? Up to now I have to compose a new HTML message and re-type all I already had in the original.